# How do i remove brightness after adding background-image?

Tags: html, css

I don't even know how to describe this, excuse me. I added an image as a 'background-image' and obviously it's small, but that's ok with me as i'm just a learner. The problem is: I don't know why there's brightness on the second repeat-image and how can i remove it?

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
       <h1>Blackjack</h1>
       <p id="message-el">Want to play a round?</p>
       <p id="cards-el">Cards: </p>
       <p id="sum-el">Sum: </p>
       <button onclick="startGame()">Start Game</button>
       <button onclick="newCard()">New Card</button>
       <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    background-image: url(https://st4.depositphotos.com/5134503/i/600/depositphotos_223688152-stock-photo-dark-green-poker-table-felt.jpg);
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', Arial, sans-serif;
    background-size: cover;
}

h1{
    color: goldenrod;
}

#message-el{
    font-style: italic;
}

button{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    color: #016f32;
    background: goldenrod;
    width: 200px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: Most likely your image has top part brighter than bottom (sort of gradient). Since you have `background-size: cover;` there should be no repeat. Try changing it's value to some other and set `background-repeat: no-repeat`

Comment: Is this your whole code? Something is missing - like you are serving this up in an iFrame or you have some height restriction on the body tag or... ??

Comment: When I run your code there is no repeat of the background image - and that is correct, there shouldn't be as you have set the background size to cover. Please could you make your code into a snippet that we can run and could you check that it does indeed show the problem. For starters try setting body's height: 100vh and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't brightness, it's your source image.  It isn't even at top and bottom.  Quick fix is to duplicate the image and flip, as I did in photoshop (see snippet).  Or you could manipulate the original image in photoshop with offset, blur and clone so the bottom and top have parity so when it repeats it will be seamless.

```css
 
   body{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/U14VE.jpg');
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', Arial, sans-serif;
    background-size: cover;
}

h1{
    color: goldenrod;
}

#message-el{
    font-style: italic;
}

button{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    color: #016f32;
    background: goldenrod;
    width: 200px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
  <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no" />

</head>

<body>
       <h1>Blackjack</h1>
       <p id="message-el">Want to play a round?</p>
       <p id="cards-el">Cards: </p>
       <p id="sum-el">Sum: </p>
       <button onclick="startGame()">Start Game</button>
       <button onclick="newCard()">New Card</button>
       <script src="index.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: While I think you're correct about the source image not being symmetric, the real mystery is why a body tag with a background-size:cover is not presenting the image as such.

Comment: It would depend on your resolution.  If you are looking at it on a desktop for instance, the way this example had the markup it will will the available space.  Scale your browser to say 500px wide and the problem will be more pronounced.

Comment: @AuthenticScience wow you did all that just to help me. Thank you very much, i appreciate your help. I thought i did something wrong in css, but it turns out it's actually the image (which wasn't remarkable for my eyes).

Comment: ヽ(´▽`)/ No prob! It only took a minute.  I deal with images a lot so it was pretty clear right away.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce brightness of an image, apply the brightness css function

```
.image {
    filter: brightness(50%);
}
```